# Django gives Secret key must not be empty error

Tags: django

I am having this issue when I try to run the server in Pycharm. I am new to Django and downloaded this project as a backend for my react application. I have generated a Secret Key using:

```
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key
print(get_random_secret_key())
exit()
```

I added this Secret key to settings.py file as well.

Error Log which I get:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Exception in thread django-main-thread:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\zabim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "C:\Users\zabim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
        raise _exception[1]
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
        autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
        app_config.ready()
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 27, in ready
        self.module.autodiscover()
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
        autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
        import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
      File "C:\Users\zabim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 6, in <module>
        from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 11, in <module>
        from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tokens.py", line 117, in <module>
        default_token_generator = PasswordResetTokenGenerator()
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tokens.py", line 18, in __init__
        self.secret = self.secret or settings.SECRET_KEY
      File "W:\Playlistify-main\Playlistify-main\server\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 90, in __getattr__
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Comment: You probably did not specify a `SECRET_KEY = '...'` in the `settings.py`.

Comment: You said you **downloaded this project**, I would not download a project unless I understand the architecture and basics of Django. 
See my answer, you should have a look at the Django tutorial as well

Answer (score 0):

Go to your settings.py

```
SECRET_KEY = ""
```

There should already be a value, if not, copy paste the one from the print statement.

Have a look at the different module for the settings, you could have one for local, production and base for example, make sure all of them have a secret key.

[Learn about secret key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key)

This is very important to understand, I strongly advise to have a look at the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/) as this error should be obvious to most beginners in Django